# Validating yaml in python similar to Json schema

Tags: python-3.x, validation, yaml, jsonschema

i need to validate several YAML files, I couldn't find something like
Json - schema, which is used for validate Json structure
Is there something like this for YAML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't something like JSON Schema for YAML because there doesn't need to be. YAML and JSON use the same data model, which means you can parse YAML and pass it to a JSON Schema validator the same way you can parse JSON and pass it to a JSON Schema validator.

In other words, JSON Schema validates YAML as well as JSON.

Comment: wow didnt know that , so i just search for YAML validation using JSON schema in python

Comment: Can you supply an example, or url for more practical information